# CursorAdapter getCount 0 on back press

Tags: android

I am loading a cursoradpater from a cursorLoader. When I first open the fragment it works as expected. But when i go to another fragment that has the same loader id and come back Adapter.getCount() returns 0 when Adapter.getCursor().getCount() returns 1. I traced the getCount method to

```
public int getCount() {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

the issue is mDataValid is false;  When i try to restart the loader it still thinks it is not valid.  How can i keep my adapter valid?

Comment: What defines `mDataValid`? Where do you change it?

Answer (score 1):

You kind of posted a small ammount of code, but i will try to help you. Everytime the dataset is invalidated (or mDataValid is false) you need to call changeCursor(). It basically means that the database has changed and the adapter needs to rebuild its cached data.

I'm assuming you have a DataSetObserver in your adapter? If so just call changeCursor in the onInvalidated() method. If you dont have one, leave a comment and i'll help you adding one to your adapter.

Comment: changeCursor() didn't work. I was able to get it to reload by creating a new adapter and restarting the loader. Not ideal cause the fragment should have all the data on back and not need to reload it

Comment: Well it should've been changeCursor(null) or changeCursor(getCursor()) depending on yoru implementation of changeCursor().

Comment: changeCursor() implementation comes from the CursorAdapter class. I tried saving the cursor from the cursorloader then changeCursor(savedCursor) on back press